# @Debug metadata crashes with TypeError

Tags: haxe, hexmachina

I have a problem with working with the automatic logging using `@Debug` metadata.

I'm receiving following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'debug' of null` - Which after some digging into generated code indicates that the logger is null.

This is my setup:

```
class SomeView implements ISomeView implements IsLoggable implements IInjectorContainer
{
    var _view:Component;

    public function new() 
    {

    }


    @Debug public function showNumber(number:Float):Void
    {
        //trace('number is: $number');
    }
}
```

In DSL I have this:

```
<view id="someView" type="my.views.SomeView />
<config id="someViewConfig" type="hex.ioc.di.MappingConfiguration" >
    <item map-name="normal" inject-into="true"> 
        <key type="Class" value="my.views.ISomeView"/>
        <value ref="someView"/>
    </item>
</config>
```

As far as I understand this should make sure that I have the logger injected.
I've also tried calling `_injector.injectInto(_myView);` in my module which is also not solving the problem.

Anyone knows how to enable the automatic debug calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/DoclerLabs/hexMachina/issues/151).
*"It's related to interfaces implementation order. When IInjectorContainer (building macro) is executed before IsLoggable one, logger property is not added to refection data and cannot be injected later."*
Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: It's fixed in hexMachina 0.8.0 https://github.com/DoclerLabs/hexMachina/releases/tag/0.8.0